# Ionic 4 ToastController buttons no async function possible

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to implement a function into the handler of my ToastController button that returns a promise (here: this.navCtrl.navigateForward()).

This is my program code:

```
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
  header: header,
  message: message,
  position: 'bottom',
  animated: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      side: 'start',
      text: 'Action',
      handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/destination');
      }
    }
  ]
});
await toast.present();
```

This gives me the info: `Promises must be handled appropriately (no-floating-promises)`
What I would like to do is this:

```
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
  header: header,
  message: message,
  position: 'bottom',
  animated: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      side: 'start',
      text: 'Action',
      handler: async () => {
        await this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/destination');
      }
    }
  ]
});
await toast.present();
```

But this gives me an error Message that is not useful at all:

```
Type '{ side: string; text: string; handler: () => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ToastButton'.
  Type '{ side: string; text: string; handler: () => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'ToastButton'.
    Types of property 'side' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"start" | "end"'.
```

I tried to find a solution but am stuck right now. Do you have any ideas where I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is ```text: 'Action,``` in your code or is it just a typo here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It was a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to await for page transition and then do something after that fact why not use .then approach?

```
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
  header: header,
  message: message,
  position: 'bottom',
  animated: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      side: 'start',
      text: 'Action',
      handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/destination').then(()=>{
            // do something after page transition?
        })
      }
    }
  ]
});
await toast.present();
```

Comment: It is the same issue with the promise chain. I also should say that is my tslint which says: Promises must be handled appropriately (no-floating-promises). With my AlertController it was the same issue and I was able to resolve it with async and await. Here it won't let me do it with my ToastController